# Wouldn't it be better to have used Java for Bitcoin Core? Is there a good cryptocurrency that went with Java from scratch?

Tags: java, satoshi-nakamoto

Java is sooooooo much easier than C++. Wondering why in 2008 people decided to go with C++ instead. Was it because Satoshi only knew C++?

And to compliment this question, is there a noticeable cryptocurrency implemented in java **from scratch**?

Comment: [tag:NXT] is written in Java. The rest of your question is pretty much open to speculation, but C++ is still one of the most used programming languages altogether.

Comment: @Close-votes: I could see somebody answering "Wouldn't it be better to have used Java for Bitcoin Core?", and "Is there a noticeable cryptocurrency implemented in java from scratch?", so maybe the question should be reduced to some subset including that instead of closed. They should be probably be asked as two separate questions though.

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one [bitcoin implementation in Java](https://bitcoinj.github.io/). Not everybody "decided to go with C++", and the choice of implementation language has no bearing on the underlying network protocol. Anybody is free to implement the bitcoin algorithm in any programming language they choose.

Speculating on which programming languages Satoshi did or did not know is pointless, because it is generally agreed that he is a fictional persona.